# DOMDocument manipulation using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to parse out a very specific part of a page using PHP and i'm currently using:"getElementsByTagName"
and it's actually working BUT, it seems that it doesn't clear everything as there are other lines with similar tags, 
so i've tried to look for a better pattern and found a unique attached "class" tag.

```
<li class="unique">
```

```
//get all li
$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('li');

//display all LI text
for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
    echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you get all LI, why do you expect it to display H1 text?

Comment: @Barmar I think that's probably a left over comment from code he pasted.

Comment: It's my mistake.. the H1 was there from the code example.. you may disregard the comment about H1

Comment: OK, but I still don't understand the question. What do you mean by not clearing everything?

Comment: @AmitSonnenschein: Is the current one not working? Does it give you any errors? How is it different from the expected output?

Comment: @Amal it's fully working, but it's giving me all outputs starting with <li.. >, and some of them are none-relevant, i'm trying to focus the search on specific <li class="unique"> ones.

Comment: perhaps you want `$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xp->query('//li[@class="unique"]');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all  the `unique` class names using an XPath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($DOM);
$items = $xpath->query('//li[@class="unique"]');
```

And loop them over:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
    echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: That did the trick...  never used xpath before - thank you for the great tip.

Comment: @AmitSonnenschein: Glad to have been of help! And yeah, XPath is very useful. Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) article for examples.